# Redis does not delete key immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, ioredis

> **EDIT** : Turns out it was the node that caused this. The for-loop somehow runs the next iteration before waits the promise to resolve. The Redis doesn't do anything here.

I have a program that iterates through an array of things i want to compare to a key in Redis. If the condition is fullfiled, i want to delete the key from the database. I'm using ioredis for this.
The code was the following :

```
async function checkthings () {
        for (const thing of list_of_things) {
            await new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                let stream = redis.scanStream({ match: '5:*'})

                stream.on("data", async function (result){
                    result.length > 0 ? console.log(result) : null;
                    stream.pause();

                    for (const key of result) {
                        let result = await redis.hgetall(key);

                        if ([CONDITIONS PUT HERE])
                             await redis.del(key);

                    }

                    stream.resume();
                })

                stream.on("end", function (){
                    console.log("Done iterating.");
                    resolve();
                })
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

The problem is when i run this code, on the first iteration everything runs normally. But on the second iteration, the key that should've been deleted was listed on the SCAN result. Even using KEYS still results on it showing up. I don't know if this was a fault at my Node.JS or the Redis.

Sorry if the question is hard to read. It's my first question.

Comment: are you using replica to read?

Comment: first iteration as in "first iteration of list of things" ?

Comment: @tuanAnhTran Yes it is.

Comment: i tried your snippet, with minor edit but the result are showing as it should be.. deleted keys are not returns in the next iteration :-/

Comment: @RoganMatrivski ah, it should be expected. my test set is too small to see the duplication. See the documentation here https://redis.io/commands/scan

Answer (score 0):

From the `SCAN` [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scan)

> A given element may be returned multiple times. It is up to the application to handle the case of duplicated elements, for example only using the returned elements in order to perform operations that are safe when re-applied multiple times.

So this should be expected from Redis's `SCAN`